# Haskell - Understanding :t [length, head] definition

Tags: haskell

Doing homework I found myself stuck with a problem. I have to go from a basic type to a "more complex" one by unifying them (the professor calls it unifying them). An example with map map:

```
map :: (c -> d) -> [c] -> [d]

map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

By replacing `c` with `a -> b`, and `d` with `[a] -> [b]` and omitting the first parameter of map, the result is `[a -> b] -> [[a] -> [b]]` which is what haskell returns when doing :t map map.

On one excercise I have `[length, head]` which according to :t in Haskell `[length, head] :: [[Int] -> Int]`

I'm having issues understanding how `[length, head]` works. It is a list of functions? It performs `head` to a list and then `length` is applied to the result?

I couldn't find an example of this working and every time i tried to input a list or list of lists to `[length,head]` it ends up in error. I noticed that `[head,length]` has the same type as `[length,head]` which did not help me understand it.

How is `[length,head]` supposed to work?

Comment: In what context are you trying to use `[length, head]` exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately because of how this homework is presented, i have to go from types length and head and reach :t [length,head] like the map example above (i'm sorry if i'm not making myself clear, it's all new to me and i'm very confused with this).
We didn't implement it anywhere and there is no example of how it works, so i really don't know how [length,head] could be implemented. As it returns something with :t in Haskell i guess i'm missing the logic of how it works

Comment: There's nothing to implement. `[length, head]` is already described in full.

Comment: If the exercise is about unifying types, it probably wants you to show how the types for `length` and `head` can be unified, which is necessary to put them both in the same list as in `[length, head]`. But it seems odd that this wouldn't be clearly stated in the homework question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm having issues understanding how `[length, head]` works. It is a list of functions?

**Yes**, it is a list with two elements, both of these elements are functions.

> It performs `head` to a list and then `length` is applied to the result?

**No**. It is simply a list with two functions, just like you can have a list of two `Char`s, or two `String`s, you can have a list of two functions. In Haskell functions are *first class citizens*, you can pass these as parameters, and return these as the result of a function. The elements in a list however always are of the same type. So that means that the `length` and the `head` in the list need to be of the same type.

This thus means that [**`head :: [a] -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:head), and [**`length :: [b] -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:length) need to be of the same type, and thus we can say that `[a] -> a` and `[b] -> Int` should be the same type. This implies that `a ~ Int` (since the return type of both functions is the same), and `a ~ b` (since the input type of the two types is the same), so as a result, the type of the two functions is `[Int] -> Int`.

So for this list, the `head` and the `length` have as type `[Int] -> Int`. It thus means that the list of these two functions has type `[[Int] -> Int]`.

Comment: Oh ok, i understand it now. Thanks!